# Spark skewedPartitionThresholdInBytes not getting enforced

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization, skew

Relatively new to spark and Curious with the behaviour of PySpark wherein ,

While performing an inner join (According to execution plan :SortMergeJoin )  using PySpark , with following parameters enabled :

```
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled  true

spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled    true

spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled     true
```

I see that there are partitions which are greater than `spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.skewedPartitionThresholdInBytes` (256 MB  the default value) during job execution.
Referring to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#optimizing-skew-join)

The Median of partition sizes come upto 18MB . `spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.skewedPartitionFactor` is also set to default value 5

However there are 2 partitions existing with sizeable skew :1454.9 MiB  and 791.5 MiB respectively .

Isn't the above parameters supposed to ensure that these 2 partitions get split to smaller ones to avoid data skew ?